# What is the regex to match a string not containing more than x consecutive characters

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I want to match strings that do not contain more than 3 of the same character repeated in a row. So:

- abaaaa [no match]
- abawdasd [match]
- abbbbasda [no match]
- bbabbabba [match]

Yes, it would be much easier and neater to do a regex match for containing the consecutive characters, and then negate that in the code afterwards. However, in this case that is not possible.

I would like to open out the question to x consecutive characters so that it can be extended to the general case to make the question and answer more useful.

Negative lookahead is supported in this case.

Comment: I've added this question because I couldn't find the answer online. I worked out the answer with some help from other SO questions. So, I figured it would be a good to share the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead with back references:

```
^(?:(.)(?!\1\1))*$
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/XFQR6n8qxQ) using your examples.

`(.)` captures each character in group 1 and the negative look ahead asserts that the next 2 chars are *not* repeats of the captured character.

Comment: 1up for a pro pattern! I would improve it like this `^(?:(.)(?!\1{2}))*$`.

Answer (score 0):

To match strings not containing a character repeated more than 3 times consecutively:

`^((.)\2?(?!\2\2))+$`

How it works:

```
^            Start of string
(
  (.)        Match any character (not a new line) and store it for back reference.
    \2?      Optionally match one more exact copies of that character.
    (?!      Make sure the upcoming character(s) is/are not the same character.
      \2\2   Repeat '\2' for as many times as you need
    )
)+           Do ad nauseam
$            End of string
```

So, the number of `/2` in your whole expression will be the number of times you allow a character to be repeated consecutively, any more and you won't get a match.

E.g.

- `^((.)\2?(?!\2\2\2))+$`       will match all strings that don't repeat a character more than 4 times in a row.
- `^((.)\2?(?!\2\2\2\2))+$`      will match all strings that don't repeat a character more than 5 times in a row.

Please be aware this solution uses negative lookahead, but not all not all regex flavors support it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this question :

[Is there a regular expression for matching a string that has no more than 2 repeating characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59275616/is-there-a-regular-expression-for-matching-a-string-that-has-no-more-than-2-repe)

which was marked as an exact duplicate of this question.

---

Its much quicker to negate the match instead

```
if (!Regex.Match("hello world", @"(.)\1{2}").Success) Console.WriteLine("No dups");
```