# Is there a regular expression for matching a string that has no more than 2 repeating characters?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm struggling to build a regex within .NET that matches when an input string does not have more than 2 repeating characters (including spaces).

Using `/(.)\1{2}/g`, I can find match when a character repeats more than 2 times. I'm looking for the opposite of this.

Example 1

- Input: Rockssaarr!&
- Match: True

Example 2

- Input: Rockssaarr!&&&
- Match: False

Example 3

- Input: Rooockssaarr!&&&
- Match: False

Comment: Which language? Also, your examples are not clear. They all have repeating characters `a`, `s` and `r`

Comment: C#. Example 1 has repeating characters but the characters only repeat twice, example 2 has a character that repeats 3 times.

Comment: You want `^(?!.*(.)\1{2})`

Comment: Its much quicker to negate the match instead, I'd show you but your question has unfortunately been marked an exact duplicate. But I'll answer it over there, to give you an idea.